# Rails 3: jQuery form not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have jquery working on my Rails app using the `gem 'jquery-rails'`.

I also have a search form working correctly. However, when I add `:remote => true` the form stops working.

```
   <%= form_tag services_path, :method => :get, :remote => true do %>

        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
       </div>
    <% end %>
```

I have also added a index.js.erb but it has no effect on it. For some reason the :remote => true makes the form to stop working.

Any reason why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curious, did you [run the install](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) task after adding the gem?

`rails generate jquery:install`

This download and installs jquery into your public folder.

If you have installed it, have you inspected your javascript console (or firebug, etc.) to see if there are any errors being generated by the javascript?